# Captured Image is blurry in my android camera app

Tags: android, image, bitmap, camera

I have developed my own camera app with some features and camera is working good.
The issue are captured images were blurred on SD card and image quality and sizes are varying on different mobiles even camera pixels are good and same. 
I don't know what is the problem on capturing and saving images in app. I have followed guidelines from developer page and few samples from github.

I couldn't find exact solutions for my problem but some samples implemented bitmap and those pic's are good in quality. I have no idea about bitmap

Any idea to solve this problem would be helpful for my further development.

Code for pictureCallBack

```
Camera.AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
        camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawPictureCallBack, null, jpegPictureCallback);
    }
};
```

Thread to save images

```
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        /**
         * Write to SD Card
         */
        try {
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyCamera");
            dir.mkdirs();

            String fileName = String.format("%d.png", System.currentTimeMillis());
            File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);

            outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            outStream.write(data[0]);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    retrieveLastImage();
                    showCustomAlert();
                }
            });
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length + " to " + outFile.getAbsolutePath());
            refreshGallery(outFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
```

Comment: Where to call setPictureSize ?

Comment: I had missed that method to set in camera parameter...Now I got good image....Thanks Oliv

Comment: Just now i have checked with another mobile it got new problem that image getting stretch while capturing and saved thin instead of usual size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks ok, I just wonder, that you save the file with `.png` extension: usually only `jpeg` is available...

Did you call [setPictureSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPictureSize%28int,%20int%29)? You need to call it, as the default size is unspecified and may be too small - blurred. You need to always call [setPreviewSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewSize%28int,%20int%29) as well.

It is tricky to choose the correct sizes. Always choose one from the sizes returned by [getSupportedPictureSizes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes%28%29) and [getSupportedPreviewSizes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes%28%29). The preview size must have the same aspect ratio as the `SurfaceView`, where you show the preview, or the preview will be stretched. Choose the picture size according to your needs.

I had lot of troubles with the camera. You will do the best if you exactly follow the [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera), or otherwise the camera behaves strangely. It might work on one device, but crash on another. I tried, for example, to set the sizes in activity's `onCreate` method, but that did not work.

Comment: Can you provide some link for that i have same problem

Answer (score 0):

To refer the below link why our camera programming getting blur images.

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

Then we have to follow this link to get clear images.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera#java

In here,

```
 Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}




@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
 }
```

- This functions are help to get the THUMBNAIL images not a whole image what we catured.